# How to display a converted string

Tags: c#

I'm working on an assignment which wants me to have the user input a string with no spaces and to identify each word by having it start with a capital letter, so "IAmName" would convert to "I Am Name". I think I have that part down, my problem is the last step, which is displaying the new string in a label, here is my code so far:

```
    private string ConvertText()
    {
        string str = inputTextBox.Text;
        if (str.Contains(" "))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No spaces allowed");
        }

        string newstring = outputLabel.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(str[i]))
                newstring += " ";
            newstring += str[i].ToString();
        }

        return newstring;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using a `StringBuilder` rather than appending to an existing string.  Because strings in C# are immutable, you are creating a new copy each time you append.  This is very inefficient. The `StringBuilder` class exists for this very purpose; it allows you to build up a string from individual substrings without creating those intermediate string objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it the other way around:

```
outputLabel.Text = ConvertText(); // Or any other label that should display it
```

I'm not sure why you have this (`string newstring = outputLabel.Text;`) inside your code though. You're not using it, you just overwrite it.

You might also want to use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate in a loop, it's a lot more efficient.

And this code probably should add a `return;`

```
if (str.Contains(" "))
{
      MessageBox.Show("No spaces allowed");
      return; // Return so it stops executing this method
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it, as for your StringBuilder, I'm in my first programming class and we have not learned about that yet, I'll look into it though.

Comment: It never hurts to get ahead of these things. Good luck in your class!

Answer (score 0):

I edited you sample a little 
I think it correct as below.

```
    public static class MyClass
{
        public static string ConvertText(string inputText)
    {
        var newstring = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < inputText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(inputText[i]))
                newstring += " ";
            newstring += inputText[i].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        } 
        return newstring;
    }
}
  string output = MyClass.ConvertText("MyNameIsBlaBla");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

> " My Name Is Bla Bla"